# Can't publish results to Sonarqube server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've set up a jenkins-sonarqube-github integration workflow where a pull request in the git repository triggers a webhook which starts a jenkins job that starts SonarQube Scanner. The issue is that I can't get it to publish to the SonarQube front-end, instead of Github.
Github results only show up to 10 top issues, and my team needs to be able to see the whole analysis result. As far as I know, that is only possible through the front-end.
The problem : I've set up two separate analysis jobs. One triggers the github commenting behavior(Sonarqube Github plugin), but I can't get the other to simply publish to the server. I've deleted all github-related configs in the latter job, but it just ends with "Success" and doesn't report anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

**Fig1. Working SonarQube Scanner properties that publish to github instead of server**

```
sonar.projectKey=${componentName}
sonar.projectVersion=0.1
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.analysis.mode=issues
sonar.profile=My_Analysis_Profile
sonar.github.repository=${repository}
sonar.github.endpoint=https://customossendpoint/api/v3
sonar.github.login=someusername
sonar.github.oauth=somehashkey123
sonar.login=id
sonar.password=pass
sonar.github.pullRequest=${pr}
sonar.host.url=http://sonarserver:19000
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true 
sonar.github.disableInlineComments=false
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes
```

**Fig2. Not working config that I tried to tweak to stop sending result to github and instead publish(send) to sonarqube server(sonar.analysis.mode=publish doesn't exist at least in sonar 6.x)**

```
sonar.projectKey=${componentName}
sonar.projectVersion=0.1
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.analysis.mode=issues
sonar.profile=My_Analysis_Profile
sonar.login=id
sonar.password=pass
sonar.host.url=http://sonarserver:19000
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=false
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes
```

**Fig3. Logs : (sorry I can't just paste the whole log here because of... corporate issues. I'll add the whole thing after censoring it if it's needed.)**

```
...
INFO: Issues mode
WARN: The use of the issues mode (sonar.analysis.mode=issues) is deprecated. This mode will be dropped in the future.
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=68ms
INFO: Server id: asdfasdf
INFO: User cache: /home1/irteam/.sonar/cache
INFO: Exclude plugins: devcockpit, ldap, authgithub, authbitbucket, pdfreport, authaad, googleanalytics, governance
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=59ms
INFO: SonarQube server 6.7.1
INFO: Default locale: "ko_KR", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
WARN: Project doesn't exist on the server. All issues will be marked as 'new'.
...
INFO: Unit Test Coverage Sensor is started
INFO: 888/888 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Integration Test Coverage Sensor is started
INFO: Overall Coverage Sensor is started
INFO: Sensor JavaScript Squid Sensor [javascript] (done) | time=72434ms
INFO: Performing issue tracking
INFO: 19822/19822 components tracked
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
INFO: Task total time: 4:31.750 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 4:33.207s
INFO: Final Memory: 72M/1513M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see, it says `WARN: Project doesn't exist on the server.` - it means it should create a new one and then publish it. However, it doesn't publish anything and just ends with "Success". No link or any report file to view, it just somehow analyzed it for itself and died without telling anyone about it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your initial property set should be working to publish to both. Are you looking in the project's SQ branches menu?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I'm not sure what you mean by the project's SQ branches menu. Are we supposed to create a new project manually before integrating the jenkins sonarqube scanner plugin? There were never any projects at all on the sonarqube frontend admin page. I've created a new one just to see if that was the problem, but creating an empty project with the same project key doesn't work either. Could you point me in the general direction to find out how to simply make jenkins sonarqube plugin upload to the sonarqube local server?

Comment: Also... I've succeeded in uploading to sonarqube server couple weeks before, but it was when I was trying to get it to upload to github, so I don't remember exactly how I did it. What I know for sure is that after I got it to send it to the server, I touched some configs again and after that it always sent to github as a comment and never again to the sonarqube local server.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the reason : Sonarqube Github plugin installed on the server prevents the server from storing any analysis results, because it doesn't allow `sonar.analysis.mode=publish`. The plugin needs to be disabled if anyone wants to see the report from the sonar server.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, and reason for it was that i had set **sonar.analysis.mode=preview**, and the goal is to run an analysis without publishing results. You can either remove if you using this mode or set to an appropriate one.

Removing this solved my issue.